# $T: \mathbb{Q}[X]\mapsto\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Proving $T$ is injective and not surjective.

Tags: functions, polynomials, rational-functions, proof-explanation

Given $T: \mathbb{Q}[X]\mapsto\mathbb{Q}[X]$, $T(f)=X\cdot X\cdot f - (X+1) \cdot f'$. Prove $T$ is injective and not surjective.

I try to prove this by applying the definition of injectiveness but I cant achieve this. I think I may be missing an important property of Rational Polynomial Functions.

Comment: Let $f,g$ in $\mathbb Q[X]$ be such that $T(f)=T(g)$.Now consider$(T(f))(-1)=(T(g))(-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Observe that $T$ is a *linear* map, as $f\mapsto g\cdot f$ and $f\mapsto f'$ are linear, so for injectivity it is enough to check that $T(f)=0$ implies $f=0$.
2. To see, it is not surjective, look at the coefficient of $X$ and the constant term of a general $T(f)$, and deduce that no nonzero constant polynomials are in the image of $T$.

Comment: For point 2, couldn't you just say that $\deg T(f) = \deg(f) + 2$? I guess that's another way of putting what you're saying.

Comment: Hey @Berci I really like your answer. It looks very elegant. Could you please expand a little bit more the point 1. My linear algebra knowledges are limited haha. Why would checking that T(f) = 0 implies f=0 would prove injectiveness.

Comment: @user2615855 Assume $T$ is not injective; then you have nonequal $f$ and $g$ for which $T(f)=T(g)$; then $T(f)-T(g)=0$ so $T(f-g)=0$ where $f-g \neq 0$. So if there is no nonzero $f$ for which $T(f)=0$ then $T$ is injective.

Comment: Great! I am starting to get. I have one more question. Is ℚ[X] a vector space? How do you know this? and how do you know T is a linear map?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a $\mathbf Q$-vector space for obvious reasons.